# Motion blur is affecting non-moving parts

Tags: rendering, rigid-body-simulation, motion-blur

[image: Without Motion Blur]
Without Motion Blur

[image: With Motion Blur]
With Motion Blur

The elements in the foreground are stationary.

Link to blend: https://drive.google.com/file/d/15RwIEsUxgMJDbkD29R1llmPtU81jgVCA/view?usp=sharing

Comment: is your camera moving?

Comment: @moonboots nope

Comment: so the objects in the foreground are not supposed to move at all at some point? maybe share your file?

Comment: correct @moonboots. Link to blend is now in the post.

Comment: it looks like there's a problem with your file, maybe use another platform?

Comment: @moonboots updated the link

Comment: are you in 3.1? Because it bugs for me in 3.1 but it works fine in 3.0

Comment: yes i am @moonboots

Comment: so please test with 3.0

Comment: does motion blur work for you in 3.1 in other projects?

Comment: works fine in 3.0

Comment: I can't find where the problem comes from (I've just tested an animation from scratch and I can't reproduce the problem), I hope someone will, but it seems to work fine in 3.0